# How to get the complete ios device details programatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, imei, uidevice

I need to access all the device details in general->settings->about in my IOS device , i can get the details except device IMEI and serial number modem firmware, there is any way to get the complete settings bundle in my application or the above mentioned details

Comment: Apple does not allow you the retrieve any device specific information like IMEI, UDID, Mac address, serial number, etc..

Comment: see updated answer to get IMEI number

Answer (score 2):

Adding `Message.framework` to your project and Get `IMEI` Number,

```
NetworkController *ntc = [NetworkController sharedInstance];
NSString *imeistring = [ntc IMEI];
```

Apple allow some of the details of device, Not give IMEI, serial Number. in `UIDevice` class provide details.

```
class UIDevice : NSObject {

    class func currentDevice() -> UIDevice

    var name: String { get } // e.g. "My iPhone"
    var model: String { get } // e.g. @"iPhone", @"iPod touch"
    var localizedModel: String { get } // localized version of model
    var systemName: String { get } // e.g. @"iOS"
    var systemVersion: String { get } // e.g. @"4.0"
    var orientation: UIDeviceOrientation { get } // return current device orientation.  this will return UIDeviceOrientationUnknown unless device orientation notifications are being generated.

    @availability(iOS, introduced=6.0)
    var identifierForVendor: NSUUID! { get } // a UUID that may be used to uniquely identify the device, same across apps from a single vendor.

    var generatesDeviceOrientationNotifications: Bool { get }
    func beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications() // nestable
    func endGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications()

    @availability(iOS, introduced=3.0)
    var batteryMonitoringEnabled: Bool // default is NO
    @availability(iOS, introduced=3.0)
    var batteryState: UIDeviceBatteryState { get } // UIDeviceBatteryStateUnknown if monitoring disabled
    @availability(iOS, introduced=3.0)
    var batteryLevel: Float { get } // 0 .. 1.0. -1.0 if UIDeviceBatteryStateUnknown

    @availability(iOS, introduced=3.0)
    var proximityMonitoringEnabled: Bool // default is NO
    @availability(iOS, introduced=3.0)
    var proximityState: Bool { get } // always returns NO if no proximity detector

    @availability(iOS, introduced=4.0)
    var multitaskingSupported: Bool { get }

    @availability(iOS, introduced=3.2)
    var userInterfaceIdiom: UIUserInterfaceIdiom { get }

    @availability(iOS, introduced=4.2)
    func playInputClick() // Plays a click only if an enabling input view is on-screen and user has enabled input clicks.
}
```

example : `[[UIDevice currentDevice] name];`

Comment: Thanks for your help.Let me know how to get device imei number?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no such API exposed by Apple to get IMEI or serial number of an iOS device programmatically. Here is a [Apple Discussion Forum Thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1713067?start=0&tstart=0) on this.