# fetch data of settings -> General -> About

Tags: ios, iphone, swift2

In the `about` section of iOS it has a lot of information about the device.

Can I and Am I allowed to access this information?

I want to fetch data of `settings -> General -> About` in swift. Is it feasible to get the same in iOS ?

Answer (score 5):

You can get the trivial ones, but interesting ones like serial number and IMEI are restricted to system apps only.

- Name: [`UIDevice.current.name`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uidevice) [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100127/how-do-you-get-an-iphones-device-name)
- Network: ?
- Number of songs, videos, photos: Use [`MPMediaQuery`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/mediaplayer/mpmediaquery), [`ALAssetsLibrary`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/assetslibrary/alassetslibrary) or [`PHPhotoLibrary`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/photos/phphotolibrary); see  [[3]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11118196/how-to-get-total-count-of-photos-from-iphone-photolibrary) and related links
- Number of apps: **Private API** [[4]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7226406/get-list-of-all-installed-apps).
- Capacity / Available: `NSFileManager` [[5]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5712527/how-to-detect-total-available-free-disk-space-on-the-iphone-ipad-device)
- OS Version: `UIDevice.current.systemVersion`
- Carrier: `CTTelephonyNetworkInfo.subscriberCellularProvider.carrierName` [[6]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28454344/how-can-i-get-details-about-the-device-data-provider-like-verizon-att-of-an-i)
- Model: **Private API**
- Serial: **Jailbreaking required**
- Wi-Fi MAC: **Jailbreaking required** [[7]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17082738/returned-mac-address-is-the-same-for-different-devices/17082875#17082875)
- Bluetooth: **Jailbreaking required**
- IMEI / MEID / ICCID / SEID: **Jailbreaking required** [[8]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18927744/get-imei-for-ios7-programmatically) (Also: [[9]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31135421/how-to-get-the-complete-ios-device-details-programatically) does not work)
- Modem firmware: ?

Answer (score 3):

Explore `UIDevice` class you will get some information programmatically:

```
UIDevice.currentDevice()
```

https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uidevice

Comment: Thanks @Dheeraj D